# Server Sent Events in React Native is returning old events inside onmessage listener instead of new ones

Tags: react-native, server-sent-events

Am trying to consume a text stream from my server. API works fine cause we have this in production for the web. Am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sse currently/ ButI've used other reavct native sse pacakges as well. Same issue.

Below is my code for react native.

```js
import EventSource from 'react-native-sse';

.
.
.

const streamUrl = getSteamUrl(question, session_id);
const source = new EventSource(streamUrl);

source.addEventListener('open', () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('Open SSE connection.');
});

  source.addEventListener('message', (e: any) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log({ val: e.data, type: e.type });
})
```

Logs are attached. The stream starts with [START] and ends with [DONE] token to identify when to consume and close the connection.
You can see they're being sent repeatedly instead of only new messages.
This same API works fine on Web. In fact, it is deployed.
I've scoured the internet, tried every React Native SSE library. All of them exhibit same behaviour. Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

You can see they're being sent repeatedly instead of only new messages.
This same API works fine on Web. In fact, it is deployed.
I expected a stream of texts like "[START]" "This" "is" "a" "message" "[DONE]"
What am getting is in the picture: "[START]" "This", then again the same with one bew word
I've scoured the internet, tried every React Native SSE library. All of them exhibit same behaviour. Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
 LOG  Open SSE connection.
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "{\"bot_message_id\": \"84a04cb5-9fd0-481f-b393-31dbff15fd73\"}"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" you\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" you\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" have\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" you\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" have\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" not\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" you\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" have\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" not\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" capped\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" you\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" have\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" not\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" capped\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" yet\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" you\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" have\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" not\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" capped\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" yet\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\".\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\",\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" you\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" have\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" not\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" capped\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\" yet\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "\".\""}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[DONE]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "[START]"}
 LOG  {"type": "message", "val": "No"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question previuosly but the answer was wrong. I encountered the same problem as you and i worked with `react-native-sse` aswell. After almost 2-3 weeks of searching, i finally found it, at least what my issue was. I switched from using react-native-sse to `react-native-event-source` and used the following code

```js
    import RNEventSource from "react-native-event-source";
    useEffect(() => {
    const eventSource = new RNEventSource(
      "http://www.yourlink.com",
      {
        headers: {
          Connection: "keep-alive",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
      }
    );

    eventSource.addEventListener("message", event => {
      const data = event.data;
      console.log(data);
    });

    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, []);
```

Instead of 'storing' or 'buffering' the given data, the application now `only receives updates`! I hope my answer helps you in a certain way and if you have questions, feel free to ask!